# Outlook API Limitations

Tags: api, email, outlook

I am new to APIs and I want to make a program that will mark certain messages as being read with meating certain conditions. It this possible to do with the outlook api.

I am looking to have the user select a time duration and maybe a list of people that will mark read too.

Also if anyone has any resources for learning their api please post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop an Outlook add-in or just automate Outlook from an external application to get the job done. The [Outlook 2013 developer reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161224.aspx) section in MSDN describes all the necessary information for developers.

See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx) to get started with an add-in. And the [How to automate Outlook and Word by using Visual C# .NET to create a pre-populated e-mail message that can be edited](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819398?wa=wsignin1.0) page describes how to automate Outlook ([C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9)).

To find items that correspond to your conditions use the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods of the Items class.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, set MailItem.UnRead property to false.

Comment: Is there a method to set that value or do you have to produce your own?

Comment: I am not sure I understand - you will need to write your own code that programmatically accesses the messages that satisfy your criteria and set the MailItem.UnRead property to false.